# API for new options while posting status

Tags: ios, facebook, integration, status

[image]

I was planning to integrate this functionality into my app. But now Facebook itself provides these options in a much better way, and I would like to implement the later one, but I could not find any API that could help me to achieve the goal.

Please help.

Comment: Facebook does not provide API for this at this moment. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, Facebook does not provide API for this at this moment.

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status